# CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION emulation

Tags: php, curl

How to emulate `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`?  This feature is disabled on my webserver.

I want to take the statistics from the site, but I can not get the right page.

Request:

```
POST https://www.example.com/login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22
Content-Length: 200
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://www.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://www.example.com/login?logout=1&final_logout=1&
Accept-Language: ru-RU
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: mochipass_session=
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

t_token=%3A1320923163%3A191098013553085002228331177770025958552%3AvcXtA5YwNT58Nt6uEGK-gvwpGqM%21&email=mytesingcomp&password=mytesingcomp&remember_me=on&login=Login&service=ads&host=www.mochimedia.com
```

Answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 11:06:40 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: example_session=mytesingcomp&1320923200&H3rV7aMe&euqh6CL4I7x2PgtWcsJa-X0n_r4!; Version=1; Expires=Thu, 24-Nov-2011 11:06:40 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Secure
Server: Example/1.0 (Any of you quaids got a smint?)
Location: https://www.example.com/login?email=mytesingcomp%40mail.ru&alias=mytesingcomp&status=verified®istered_service=ads×tamp=1320923200&nonce=hmCFzV-9&hmac=EHNUJYf2dbVsg8Y-J7iEdzgHyT0%21&login=login
Content-Length: 46
X-Example-Server: 38.102.129.29:443
P3P: policyref="http://www.example.com/p3p/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE GOV"
X-Example-Backend: 10.0.0.107:40061
X-Example-Source: 10.0.0.237:44200

CONGRATULATIONS, you're logged in. Redirecting
```

Now we need make redirect, how make it with cURL?

Comment: isn't your question self-answerous? Use curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Comment: No, i can't use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, i need emulate it.

Comment: So, read header "Location" if HTTP Code is 30x, do what you want and go to that location manually

Comment: "No, i can't use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION" - please elaborate

Comment: Yes, i read location data and manually go there, of course with cookies, but  there is no right page. Possibly i need more info for cUrl data.

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is disabled on my hosting.

Comment: The right page must consist this line: Set-Cookie: s_login=63bf0ca7f1d99425b114cffb1d350c981320923201|mytesingcomp|mytesingcomp; expires="Thu, 24-Nov-2011 11:06:41 GMT"; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; secure

Comment: You might want to switch over to using [`Zend_Http_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html), which will allow you to bypass cURL entirely in case any additional features that you need are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

well, try use default construction, such as:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

if this not help you, try manualy parse head answer, something like:

```
if (preg_match('/Location: (.+?)[\r\n]+/', $page, $m)) {
    $location = $m[1];
    $page = curl_get($location);
}
```

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION only works on local server, but disabled on my hosting (open_basedir problem).

Comment: well, then don't use FOLLOWLOCATION;try manually parse answer, and manually get new page

Answer (score -1):

The problem solved! I needed to add only two lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

Hope it helps anybody.